# How to access the check box displayed using adapter in the activity containing list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am working on the following screen:

[image: New Group screen]

The friends list is displayed by populating listview using Base Adapter.

**Adapter**

```
  public class Adapter_Friends_Group extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;

    public Adapter_Friends_Group(Context context, List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listBeanFriends = listBeanFriends;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listBeanFriends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listBeanFriends.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_friends, null);
        }

        //finding different views
        ImageView pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendsImage);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFriends);
        CheckBox chkFriends = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkFriends);

        final Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String name = bean_friends.getName();
        String url = bean_friends.getUrl();
        String extension = bean_friends.getExtension();
        apiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
        String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
        String absolute_url = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;

        //loading image into ImageView                                                                                                                                            iew
        Picasso.with(context).load(absolute_url).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(pic);

        //Setting name in the textview
        txtName.setText(name);

        chkFriends.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.e("Checkboxxxxxxxxxx", "Clicked");
                if (isChecked) {
                    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("true");
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "Checked");
                } else {
                    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("false");
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "UnChecked");
                }
                listBeanFriends.add(bean_friends);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

When the check box is clicked,I am saving a string value as true in the Bean.

**Bean**

```
public class Bean_Friends {
    private String name, url, extension, friendsID;
    private String friendSelected;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getFriendsID() {
        return friendsID;
    }

    public void setFriendsID(String friendsID) {
        this.friendsID = friendsID;
    }

    public String getFriendSelected() {
        return friendSelected;
    }

    public void setFriendSelected(String friendSelected) {
        this.friendSelected = friendSelected;
    }
}
```

Now inside the activity containing list view,In want to access the id of the friend whose check box is checked on clicking single tick on the Top Toolbar.

Following method is used on clicking single tick:

```
public void createNewGroup() {
    Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    listBeanFriends = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listBeanFriends.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Loop Working", "-------------");
        Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String friendSelected = bean_friends.getFriendSelected();
        String friendID = bean_friends.getFriendsID();
        Log.e("FriendID", friendID);
        if (friendSelected.equals("true")) {
            Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, friendID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is mot working for me .I want to access the id of friends whose check box is checked on clicking single tick.Please help me to fix the issue.

**Updated Code:**

I have done the following changes.Now it is working for me now.

**Adapter**

```
    public class Adapter_Friends_Group extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
    private Bean_Friends bean_friends;


    public Adapter_Friends_Group(Context context, List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listBeanFriends = listBeanFriends;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtName;
        CheckBox chkFriend;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listBeanFriends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listBeanFriends.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_friends, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendsImage);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFriends);
            viewHolder.chkFriend = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkFriends);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String name = bean_friends.getName();
        String url = bean_friends.getUrl();
        String extension = bean_friends.getExtension();
        apiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
        String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
        String absolute_url = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;

        //loading image into ImageView                                                                                                                                            iew
        Picasso.with(context).load(absolute_url).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        //Setting name in the textview
        viewHolder.txtName.setText(name);
        //Setting boolean isSelected if the Checkbox is checked
        viewHolder.chkFriend.setChecked(bean_friends.isSelected());
        viewHolder.chkFriend.setTag(bean_friends);


        viewHolder.chkFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                Bean_Friends bean_friends = (Bean_Friends) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on Checkbox: " + bean_friends.getName() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bean_friends.setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Bean**

```
  public class Bean_Friends {
    private String name, url, extension, friendsID;
    boolean isSelected;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getFriendsID() {
        return friendsID;
    }

    public void setFriendsID(String friendsID) {
        this.friendsID = friendsID;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

**Method inside Activity**

```
 public void createNewGroup() {
    StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
    listBeanFriends = adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends;
    //  Log.e("Size of adapter_friends", String.valueOf(adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends.size()));
    Log.e("Size of listbeanFriends", String.valueOf(listBeanFriends.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < listBeanFriends.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Loop Working", String.valueOf(i));
        Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String friendID = bean_friends.getFriendsID();
        String friendName = bean_friends.getName();
        Log.e("FriendsName", friendName);
        Log.e("FriendID", friendID);
        Log.e("FriendSelected", String.valueOf(bean_friends.isSelected()));
        if (bean_friends.isSelected()) {
            responseText.append("\n" + bean_friends.getName() + "  " + bean_friends.getFriendsID());
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, responseText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: in which class funciton createNewGroup() is implemented ?

Comment: i think you are using list out side of adapter.
you are reinitialize list in createNewGroup() funciton.
when you are using list in createNewGroup() function first get list from adapter because that is updated list..

Comment: createNewGroup() method is implemented  in the NewGroupActivity class which contains list view.

Comment: You are reinitializing at this line
listBeanFriends = new ArrayList<>();
get listBeanFriends from adapter.

Comment: It is giving me NullPointerException inside the loop when i am displaying friendID. Exception is raised when the loop is working for last time.Suppose we have 5 elements in the list.SO for the 5th element it is giving me null value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link will help you :

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.After following this link ,i have made some changes in my code.I have added my working code now.The Problem is fixed now .

Answer (score 1):

try replacing this line

```
listBeanFriends = new ArrayList<>();
```

with:

```
List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends = new ArrayList<>();
    listBeanFriends = adapter.listBeanFriends;
```

Comment: It is giving me NullPointerException inside the loop when i am displaying friendID. Exception is raised when the loop  is working for last time.Suppose we have 5 elements in the list.SO for the 5th element it is giving me null value .

Comment: are you getting other IDs which are checked?

Comment: yes i am getting other IDs which are checked and unchecked also.

Comment: ok then your problem is almost solve let me think about nullpointer

Comment: check size of listBeanFriends and adapter.listBeanFriends in log and tell me answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104624/discussion-between-parsania-hardik-and-deepakr).